# Numbering different number of PC using subnet masking

Tags: ip, ip-address, ipv4, subnet

Suppose, There are 5 departments with the following number of PCs:

```
Department A: 50 PCs
Department B: 10 PCs
Department C: 25 PCs
Department D: 40 PCs
```

If the networks address is **192.168.10.0/24** and if I want to divide the network among the above departments (for numbering the PCs) using subnet masking, then what will be the first and last usable IP address of each department?

Answer (score 0):

You should really put some effort into this as it's a really easy solution ..

You need to use [VLSM](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/subnetting-supernetting-and-vlsm/vlsm.html) to split the network 192.168.10.0/24. First of all, you start with the department that has the most amount of users (department A). To accomodate 50 users, we'll need to use a subnet mask that gives us 62 usable hosts (64-2).

```
Department A: 50 users
Network 192.168.10.0 - 192.168.10.63
Subnet mask of 255.255.255.192 (/26)
First usable is 192.168.10.1 
Last usable is 192.168.10.62
```

The second department is department D, with 40 users, which also needs a /26 subnet mask.

```
Department D: 40 users
Network 192.168.10.64 - 192.168.10.127
Subnet mask of 255.255.255.192 (/26)
First usable is 192.168.10.65
Last usable is 192.168.10.126
```

The third department is department C, with 25 users. To accomodate 25 users, we'll need to use a subnet mask that gives us 30 usable hosts (32-2).

```
Department C: 25 users
Network 192.168.10.128 - 192.168.10.159
Subnet mask of 255.255.255.224 (/27)
First usable is 192.168.10.129
Last usable is 192.168.10.158
```

The last department is department B, with 10 users. To accomodate 10 users, we'll need to use a subnet mask that gives us 14 usable hosts (16-2).

```
Department B: 10 users
Network 192.168.10.160 - 192.168.10.175
Subnet mask of 255.255.255.240 (/28)
First usable is 192.168.10.161
Last usable is 192.168.10.174
```